# Библиотеки распознавания речи

Tags: java, аудио, c++

Есть на Java или C++ открытые библиотеки по распознаванию речи?

Comment: а откуда такой размах от спп до джавы?))

Comment: Вот эту статью смотрел sapi 5?
http://www.speech-text.narod.ru/chap5.html

Comment: Нифига тут интерфейс не понял кому отвечаю)
За статью спасибо. А первый вопрос не очень понял)

Comment: зачем тебе эти либы? просто так интересуешся?

Comment: Не бибилотека, но мб пригодится: [Простой алгоритм распознавания речи по короткому словарю на основе MFCC](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150251/)

Comment: Интересуюсь насколько это сложно, а так подумал себе помощника написать. Какая разница на каком языке?

Comment: Спасибо, пригодится

Comment: Вот это у тебя ник конечно, а главное не забанили же...

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) (Open Source Toolkit For Speech Recognition).

> Продукт с открытым исходным кодом для распознавания речи, который включает библиотека распознавания, написанную на C, модифицируемый, изменяемый распознаватель написан на Java.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю. Кажется то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Где достать сами движки распознавания речи?
В windows 7 их нет для русской версии.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sphelper.h"

short main()
{
    std::system("chcp 1251");

    // Declare local identifiers:
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CComPtr<ISpRecoContext> cpRecoContext;
    CComPtr<ISpVoice> cpVoice;

    if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL))) {
        std::cout << "n1) Инициализация объекта COM не выполнена!";
    } else {
        std::cout << "n1) Инициализация объекта COM выполнена!";
    }

hr = S_OK;
unsigned long num_engines = 0;
//
if (SUCCEEDED (hr))
{ 
std::cout << "\n 1) Получаем движки распознования: ";
hr = SpEnumTokens(SPCAT_RECOGNIZERS, NULL,  NULL, &token);
}
if (SUCCEEDED (hr))
{
hr = token->GetCount(&num_engines); 
std::cout << "\n 2) Всего движков: " << num_engines;
}

    // Create a shared recognition context.
    hr = cpRecoContext.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpSharedRecognizer);        // CLSID_SpInProcRecoContext  CLSID_SpSharedRecoContext

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        // Create a voice from the context (with
        // same audio format as context)
        hr = cpRecoContext->GetVoice(&cpVoice);
    } else {
        std::cout << "nустройство не создано";
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        // Tell the associated Voice to stop speaking when
        // the SR Engine hears a recognizable sound.
        hr = cpRecoContext->SetVoicePurgeEvent(SPFEI(SPEI_SOUND_START));
    } else {
        std::cout << "nGetVoice() не сработал";
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        // Do stuff here.
        std::cout << "nуспешно";
    } else {
        std::cout << "nне успешно";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать [Vosk](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api). Преимущества библиотеки:

- Поддерживает 8 языков - русский, английский, немецкий, французский,
  португальский, испанский, китайский, вьетнамский. В скором времени
  будут добавлены и другие
- Работает без доступа к сети даже на
  мобильных устройствах - Raspberry Pi, Android, iOS
- Модели для каждого языка занимают всего 50Мб, но есть и гораздо более
  точные большие модели для более точного распознавания
- Сделана для потоковой обработки звука, что позволяет реализовать мгновенную
  реакцию на команды
- Поддерживает несколько популярных языков программирования - C++, C, Java, C#, Javascript

  - Позволяет быстро настраивать словарь распознавания для улучшения точности распознавания
  - Позволяет идентифицировать говорящего

Пример работы на Java [такой](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/blob/master/java/test/DecoderTest.java):

```java
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.*;

import org.kaldi.KaldiRecognizer;
import org.kaldi.Model;
import org.kaldi.SpkModel;

public class DecoderTest {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("vosk_jni");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream ais = new FileInputStream(new File("../python/example/test.wav"));
        Model model = new Model("model-en");
        SpkModel spkModel = new SpkModel("model-spk");
        KaldiRecognizer rec = new KaldiRecognizer(model, spkModel, 16000.0f);

        int nbytes;
        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        while ((nbytes = ais.read(b)) >= 0) {
            if (rec.AcceptWaveform(b)) {
                System.out.println(rec.Result());
            } else {
                System.out.println(rec.PartialResult());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(rec.FinalResult());
    }
}
```